# Powerful wizard

Tags: pattern

A powerful wizard have to be able to:

- Turn a *plate* into a *pencil*
- Turn a *ceramic bowl* into a *cue ball*
- Turn a *kettlebell* into a *rubber band*
- Turn a *plastic bag* into a *concrete block*

**Questions:**

1. What can he turn a *scissor* into?
2. Name an object that a wizard cannot turn into anything else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may be wildly off, but I'm going to guess anyways:

A powerful wizard can turn an object into another object, that

> 1. has the same [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics))
>  2. can somehow be contained within it

Here's how these conditions would fit the given samples:

- Turn a *plate* into a *pencil*

> Both have zero holes, and a pencil can fit on a plate

- Turn a *ceramic bowl* into a *cue ball*

> Both have zero holes, and a cue ball would fit inside a ceramic bowl

- Turn a *kettlebell* into a *rubber band*

> Both have one hole, and a kettlebell is often wrapped in rubber (except for the handle) to prevent damage to the floor; the wrapping rubber is essentially a wide rubber band

- Turn a *plastic bag* into a *concrete block*

> Both have two holes (a plastic bag has handles, a concrete block has usually two holes, see picture below) and a concrete block would probably fit inside a plastic bag) 
>  [image]

So unless I am completely in the dark (absolutely not ruling that possibility out), a scissor can be turned into

> **a wedding band** (one hole each, a scissor contains a metal ring that you put a finger through)

and something that cannot be transformed into anything else could be

> **[a Klein bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle)**, whose inside isn't distinguishable from its outside, and therefore it cannot contain anything. In addition to this, it has a different genus from all objects in the real universe.

Wish me luck! :-)

Comment: Great work :) he cannot turn a scissor into that however. A rot13(grncbg jvgu ab yvq) is a more suitable answer.

Comment: Forgive me for nitpicking, but ["scissor, singular"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scissor#Noun) is either half a pair of scissors, and only has one hole, or it refers to [the pair](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d2/Scissor.JPG/330px-Scissor.JPG), which is two separate items, each of which have only one hole. Neither of these work for a rot13(grncbg jvgu ab yvq).

Comment: [Obligatory abstruse goose](https://abstrusegoose.com/253)

Comment: I'm not sure what point 2 adds to this answer. Point 1 is sufficient by itself to explain the examples given, and there are no examples of objects which cannot be transmuted that would require the addition of point 2 to explain. By [Occam's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), we can do away with point 2, surely?

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails to eliminate other possible answers that may be equally correct (word pattern, phrase pattern, etc.)

Comment: @MinhTran Sorry, I was referring to the requirement numbered 2 in this answer, not the one in your question.

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails, point 2 is necessary to tighten the fit. A rule consisting of the two related parts (both related to topology) is a lot more selective than just point 1 alone. If the answer only had point 1, it would be easy to come up with other rules that fit just as well or even better, which would make the solution ambiguous, thus ruining the puzzle. Finding another fitting rule as selective as points 1 and 2 combined, on the other hand, is much more difficult.